# How to make code compatibility with access 2010 which is written in access 2016. Getting the error "Cannot find the library"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written the code in Access 2016 to upload the data in access database. I have shared the same with audience who have access 2010 on their system but they get the error when open the Front End "Compiler error"

When I started debugging on system which has office 2010 then there was error on Date function I changed it with Now. Then it was showing error with Format function and so on. Please advise what else I can try and can change in my code to work on both versions 2010 and 2016.

Code Line:

```
tbatchid = "GOSC" & Format(Me.Txtsdate.Value, "ddmmyyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a *missing reference*.

Go to menu *Tools, References* and check if any reference is marked MISSING and resolve that.

You may have to develop in Access 2010 (the earliest version). That will typically not create this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use Microsoft Access databases 'cross-over' multiple Access versions you should prepare them by decompiling (and compacting) them before distribution to remove any hidden code compilations:

`"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "c:\Folder\Database.accdb" /decompile /compact`